# How to convert list of adjacent nodes into a graph (adjacency list)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a text file that contains all of the connections in an undirected graph it looks like:

```
N_0, N_2
N_5, N_3
N_3, N_2
```

and so on. With this text file, I want to generate a graph to run DFS on it.

Here is my thought process:

I turn the file into a 2D array, find how many elements there are, and create an adjacency list using this information.

This is what I have so far

```
fileName = input("Enter text file name: ")

# Create 2D array of connected nodes
with open(fileName, "r") as file:
    data = [[str(x) for x in line.replace('\n', '').split(",")] for line in file]

#Create list of unique nodes and sort them
nodeList = list(set(i for j in data for i in j))
nodeList.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[x.find('_') + 1:]))

adjacencyList = dict(nodeList)
```

I am stuck on how to proceed. I can't convert the nodeList into a dictionary, and after I do I'm not sure how to load the connections into it. I guess just iterate through the data and mark down on the dictionary all of the connections?

Any advice on how to proceed is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use `networkx` module?

Comment: You just end up with a dictionary where the node name is the key, and the value is a list of strings.  You don't need to generate or sort the list of nodes -- you can get that from the dict keys afterward.

Comment: I can use networkx, I've just never used it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the adjacency dictionary when you read the file.  You can fetch the list of nodes by getting the keys from that dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Create 2D array of connected nodes
nodes = defaultdict(list)
for line in open('x.txt'):
    a,b = line.rstrip().split(', ')
    nodes[a].append( b )
    nodes[b].append( a )

print(nodes)
print(list(nodes.keys()))
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'N_0': ['N_2'], 'N_2': ['N_0', 'N_3'], 'N_5': ['N_3'], 'N_3': ['N_5', 'N_2']})
['N_0', 'N_2', 'N_5', 'N_3']
```

However, the suggestion to use `networkx` is still the best plan

Comment: Thank you! This method works for me. Its much simpler than what I was doing lol

Comment: Is there a way to sort the new dictionary so it would be 
{ N_0: [N_2], N_2: [N_0, N_3], N_3: [N_2] and so on?

Comment: Yes, if it's not a directed graph, then you just change the loop to make entries in both directions, a->b and b->a.